# how to remove an item from menu navbar?

Tags: magento2, menu

"**Removing unnecessary item from top nav-menu**"

Earlier for testing I'd added category called blog new and then i deleted it but now its still visible but it doesn't have any class and its disturbing the alignment of menu, how do i remove it?

*I've already tried to find it but it doesn't have a class so could not find it through **grep command**.*

Comment: Have you reindexed and cleared the cache?

Comment: yes i've done it

Comment: is it the default Magento menu?

Comment: The main menu system is populated by the DB, so looking for that element in the code with grep wont give you any results that would be helpful. All the of the menu is manageable in the admin, so looking at that category structure should tell you what's happening.